# "No value given for one or more required parameters." Access C# Simple Select

Tags: c#, ms-access, select, parameters, oledb

**Error Returned:**

"No value given for one or more required parameters."

**String Array to pass to function:**

```
String[,] arrParams = new String[1, 2] {
                       {"@ToUpper_user_id", id}
                };
```

**Value of id:**

```
"test" (without the quotes)
```

**SQL:**

```
strSQL = "select * from users where ToUpper_user_id = ?;";
```

**SQL Function Call:**

```
if (jdb.getdb_data(strSQL, arrParams, strTableName, out dsGet, out strTechMessage))
{
    ...
}
```

**Function that calls to get data from the db:**

```
public static bool getdb_data(String strSQL, String[,] arrParams, String strTableName, out DataSet dsGet, out String strTechMessage)
    {
        bool boolRC = true;
        String key = String.Empty;
        String val = String.Empty;

        dsGet = new DataSet();
        strTechMessage = String.Empty;
        String strSQL_Empty = String.Empty;

        string connectionString = jdb.getConnString();

        using (OleDbConnection connection =
            new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);

            if (arrParams.GetLength(0) > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrParams.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arrParams.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        if (j.Equals(0)) { key = arrParams[i, j]; }
                        if (j.Equals(1)) { val = arrParams[i, j]; }
                    }

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, val);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                boolRC = false;
                strTechMessage = "No parameters found";
            }

            // Open the connection in a try/catch block. 
            // Create and execute the DataReader, writing the result
            // set to the console window.
            if (boolRC)
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, connection);

                    adapter.Fill(dsGet, strTableName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    boolRC = false;
                    strTechMessage = ex.Message;
                }
            }

        }

        return boolRC;
    }
```

***Please help - I think I am goin' insane! (The Update CRUD all works with parameters . . . just the select code is giving me the error.)***

Comment: Do you really have a column named exactly ToUpper_user_id?

Comment: After you fix this, I see a `datatype mismatch` error in your future.

Answer (score 0):

In "get_dbdata(...)" above, I should have have had:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
```

instead of:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, connection);
```

In the code, both the sql and parameters have already been added to the command above.

Works now!